# Failed to compile React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty sure I just don't have proper syntax but an't seem to figure out the correct syntax. Here's my code (it is inside of a `return()` and that return is inside of a `render(){}` along with html.

```
<div className="questions">
  Now let's add some questions... <br />
  {// This is where we loop through our questions to
  // add them to the DOM.
  this.state.questions.map(question => {
    return (
      <div>
        {question}
        {
          for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            answers.push(
              <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                name={uuid()}
              />
            );
          }
        }
      </div>
    );
  })
</div>
```

I am very new to this so any help would be super helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pushing to an `answers` array inside of your JSX but never using it. You could instead push to the array before your return statement and then use it in the JSX.

```
this.state.questions.map(question => {
  const answers = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    answers.push(
      <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {question}
      {answers}
    </div>
  );
});
```

Alternatively, you could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
<div className="questions">
  Now let's add some questions... <br />
  {this.state.questions.map(question => {
    return (
      <div>
        {question}
        {Array.from({ length: 4 }, () => (
          <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
```